# SILVERLIGHT: How to access a restful service from silverlight

Tags: silverlight, rest, wcf-rest, wcf-rest-starting-guide

What is the standard way of accessing a restful service from silverlight (I am targetting v3 of silverlight)?

In .net i use REST Starter KIT but its not compatible with Silverlight - although i did find a port but unsure weather to try it.

Is there a standard way to access rest from silverlight?

Any good examples or tutorials?

Also is there an equivelant of ReadAsDataContract for populating a .net class from the restful service?

Any help really appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use ClientHttpStack and System.Runtime.Serialization**

Take a look at the [Client HTTP Stack](http://www.silverlightplayground.org/post/2009/07/10/Silverlight-30-RTW-A-new-HTTP-stack-ready-for-REST.aspx) for Silverlight, you'll need this to implement REST properly.

You can turn your ResponseStream into an object using System.Runtime.Serialization's DataContractSerializer.

Answer (score 3):

here is a pretty basic tutorial on that: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/pages/silverlight-tutorial-part-3-using-networking-to-retrieve-data-and-populate-a-datagrid.aspx